# Selenium works only when I'm connected to a remote server

Tags: python, selenium, cron, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run a simple Selenium chrome-driver test on a remote Ubuntu server (EC2).

In order to run the code immediately after rebooting, I define the following crontab entry:

```
@reboot export DISPLAY=:0 && export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin && nohup /usr/bin/python3  /home/ubuntu/test/play/client.py 60 http://192.162.2.2:8080 &
```

And the `client.py` code as follows:

```
import sys
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display


def play(test_duration, address):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
    display = Display(visible=False)
    display.start()

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(address)
    play_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/div/div[1]/button[1]')  # play button
    send_stats_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/div/div[1]/button[2]')  # get statistics
    play_btn.click()
    time.sleep(test_duration)
    send_stats_btn.click()

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
    display.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_duration = int(sys.argv[1])
    address = sys.argv[2]
    play(test_duration, address)
```

The strange thing is that the script worked **perfectly** when I connected to the machine (rebooting and then logging back in). However, when I logout, I receive the following error:

```
Message: Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing the chrome driver initialization as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
```